# Meaning of "almost all" in Terrence Tao's work on the Collatz map

Tags: number-theory, terminology

I have read (just a few pages) from Terrence Tao's September 2019 work on the Collatz map here,

> ["Almost all orbits of the Collatz map attain almost bounded values" (via arXiv.org)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562)

It's interesting and he stated and introduced the matter clearly. I, however, have something that I'm not sure I understand it correctly - the term  *Almost all* he used as I did search for more of the definition.

The term *almost all* have at least $2$ senses as *natural density* and *logarithmic density*. Wikipedia said that the set $\mathbb{A}\subset\mathbb{N}$ is said to be *almost all* of the natural number in the sense of *logarithmic density* if the following limit exists and is unity, $$\delta(\mathbb{A})=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{\log x}\sum_{n\in \mathbb{A},n\le x}\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$
I think this is quite make sense, since $\displaystyle 1>\gamma=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}+\sum_{j=1}^x\dfrac{1}{j}-\log x$ and of course, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\log x}\sum_{j}\dfrac{1}{n}=1$. So *almost all* should imply something like this limit, which is *all* . Anyway, does this seems correct to you?