# What does "almost all in the sense of logarithmic density" mean in Tao's Collatz paper?

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory, terminology

Tao's paper: ["Almost all orbits of the Collatz map attain almost bounded values" (via arXiv.org)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562)

- 1st related question/discussion, I did not understand: [Meaning of "almost all" in Terrence Tao's work on the Collatz map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690985/meaning-of-almost-all-in-terrence-taos-work-on-the-collatz-map)
- 2nd related question/discussion, I did not understand: [Notion of "almost all" using probability theory by Terence Tao](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727557/notion-of-almost-all-using-probability-theory-by-terence-tao)
- Quora discussion did not make it clearer: [Is Terence Tao's paper on Collatz conjecture using probability theory any indication to the actual truth of the conjecture? Also, how is this any better than verifying this for larger and larger numbers?](https://www.quora.com/Is-Terence-Taos-paper-on-Collatz-conjecture-using-probability-theory-any-indication-to-the-actual-truth-of-the-conjecture-Also-how-is-this-any-better-than-verifying-this-for-larger-and-larger-numbers)
- Google did not help: [What does "almost all" mean in Taos paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20does%20%22almost%20all%22%20mean%20in%20Taos%20paper)

I understand that Tao's paper is very high level, but can someone possibly explain the meaning of "*almost all in the sense of logarithmic density*" in a way that *any level* can understand, *in layman's terms*?

For example, if we call **A** the set of those "*almost all*" numbers, and **Ac** the complement set within $\mathbb{N}$, the set of all remaining numbers in $\mathbb{N}$,
then:

1. Does "almost all" mean that the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of **Ac** is 0?
2. Does "almost all" mean that the [logarithmic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Other_density_functions) of **Ac** is
   0?
3. Both?
4. Neither?

And if neither, than what does "*almost all in the sense of logarithmic density*" mean, *in layman's terms*?

Comment: If there’s no discussion in the paper on what this means, it’s probably option 2, which is the most natural interpretation, and anything else would have likely required more elaboration. Option 1 directly contradicts the precision “in the sense of logarithmic density”. Apparently, option 2 implies option 3, because the upper natural density is always higher than the upper logarithmic density.

Comment: @aphelli thank you - I did not mean for 1 and 2 to be exclusive of each other, my mistake - but I am a bit confused by your comment that "2 implies 3"? If natural is always higher than logarithmic, wouldn't that mean that "1 implies 3"?

Comment: Oops, you’re right, my mistake. The general result is that the “logarithmic density interval” (between lower and upper densities) is contained in the “natural density interval”, so yes, it’s option 1 that’s equivalent to option 3, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @aphelli so, if I understand correctly, we have by definition 0<=LowNatD<=LowLogD<=UppLogD<=UppNatD, right? And 2 being true means LogD=0 and thus 0=LowNatD=LowLogD=UppLogD<=UppNatD ?